# UITableViewSource. Adding data from List

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have a timetable in the form of the XML:

`<timetable>
    <lesson>
        <nameOfLesson>Chemistry</nameOfLesson>
        <day>16.02.2015</day>
        <weekday>Monday</weekday>
        <time>11:05-12:35</time>
        <audience>514</audience>
    </lesson>
    <lesson>
        <nameOfLesson>Mathematics</nameOfLesson>
        <day>16.02.2015</day>
        <weekday>Monday</weekday>
        <time>13:00-14:30</time>
        <audience>514</audience>
    </lesson>
<timetable>`

I add the data to the `List<Lesson>`. And then all the data from the List should be added to the cell in TableView, but I do not know how better to take the data from the List because IndexPath.Row always starts from zero at the transition to a new section.

This is Lesson Class:

`public class Lesson
{
    public string name, day, dayOfWeek, time, audience;
    public Lesson(string _name, string _day, string _dayOfWeek, string _time, string _audience)
    {
         this.name = _name;
         this.day = _day;
         this.dayOfWeek = _dayOfWeek;
         this.time = _time;
         this.audience = _audience;
    }
}`

Second option filling xml:

`<timetable>
    <day>
        <lesson>
            <nameOfLesson></nameOfLesson>
            <date>16.02.2015</date>
            <weekday>Monday</weekday>
            <time>11:05-12:35</time>
            <audience>514</audience>
        </lesson>
        <lesson>
            <nameOfLesson></nameOfLesson>
            <date>16.02.2015</date>
            <weekday>Monday</weekday>
            <time>13:00-14:30</time>
            <audience>514</audience>
        </lesson>
        <lesson>
            <nameOfLesson></nameOfLesson>
            <date>16.02.2015</date>
            <weekday>Monday</weekday>
            <time>14:40-16:10</time>
            <audience>514</audience>
        </lesson>
    </day>
    <day>
        <lesson>
            <nameOfLesson></nameOfLesson>
            <date>17.02.2015</date>
            <weekday>Tuesday</weekday>
            <time>13:00-14:30</time>
            <audience>602</audience>
        </lesson>
        <lesson>
            <nameOfLesson></nameOfLesson>
            <date>17.02.2015</date>
            <weekday>Tuesday</weekday>
            <time>14:40-16:10</time>
            <audience>602</audience>
        </lesson>
    </day>
</timetable>`

Comment: How many sections does your table have?  How are the lessons grouped?

Comment: So much the number of days in the calendar says. From one to seven. Lessons could not be grouped. There is a second option of filling xml file there lessons with the same day of the week are grouped in a separate <day>

Comment: I add second option filling xml.